Using Telethon with webhooks
I'm using the telethon lib to build a telegram bot. However, when trying to implement a webhook system, to avoid polling, I get this exception:
raise RuntimeError('The asyncio event loop must not change after connection (see the FAQ for details)')
RuntimeError: The asyncio event loop must not change after connection (see the FAQ for details)

I've checked the FAQ and got a few hints at the problem. However, this made me wonder, is there a simpler way to use a webhook and easilly dispatch the updates to telethon client?
Any help is apreciated, I'm stuck.
I've tried running my server with asyncio.run(), however that triggered even more exceptions.
I even tried to write:
client.loop.run_until_complete(uvicorn.run(app, host="localhost", port=8001))

But I still get the same exception.

What are all the libraries you're using? Is any using threads? Can you use asyncio-based alternatives? Otherwise, create a Telethon client and asyncio event loop there, and use it only through there, with thread-safe queues when you need to communicate from elsewhere.

I tried Telethon client loop to run my server (I'm using FastAPI) but I still get the same exception. I'm only using Telethon
